# How to do lookup and group two collections in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

i have two collections player and score. Where playerID is the common field.  But i want to join them and make a groupby on their playerID,position, sum(run), sum(catch), max(score)

The position will be the related position to their max(score).

The output will like,

```
playerID --- Name --- Run -- Catch -- Position -- score
1001    ---- Abid --- 123 -- 12    -- Batting   --- 123
1234    ---- Look ---- 234 --23    -- Fielding  -- 200
```

I share some of my data of two collections. They are large dataset so the query should be optimized to run first.

Player collections

[image: player collection]

Score collections

[image]

Comment: post some documents in json format instead of screenshots, and also post expected result in json format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is very useful to think in documents and not in tables when working with MongoDB.

You can do it using Mongo Aggregation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).